# Should the logging utilities be exposed as public API?

Tags: c++, logging

In my library I've got a `Logger` class that is a wrapper around `spdlog`, that I use internally for logging. Logging is enabled by default in Debug builds and disabled in Release builds, moreover user can force enable logging in Release builds via CMake option. Also logging level is `spdlog::level::trace` by default.

There is no way for a user of my library to change logging level without changing library's source code, which might not be possible when linking against binaries directly. What is a standard approach for handling logging (disabling logging in Debug builds, changing logging levels etc.) when my library will be used by other people? Should the logging utilities be exposed as a public API?

Comment: There is no "standard" which releases you from making a requirements analysis. **You** have to find out **by yourself** whether your users of **your specific library** have the requirement of controlling the logging behaviour at run time in the Release build, or if controlling it at compile time is sufficient. Strangers from the internet cannot tell you what makes most sense for your specific case.

Comment: Logging is often a kind of cross-cutting concern where normal API design guidelines don't quite apply. It absolutely makes sense for consumers of the library to adjust the libraries log level, and to configure how log events are handled (e.g. written to a file, stored in a database, …). I'm not familiar with spdlog, but from skimming its docs the appropriate way to use it in a library would be for your lib to locate a named logger in the global registry, and require your downstream users to provide a suitable logger under that name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I used to detect at runtime whether the application was running under a debugger and logging/asserts etc. were dependent on that. Because you can have unintended differences between debug and release build and want to be able to debug a release build as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are shipping code to (hopefully!) happy users.
Then a support issue arises where you and/or the user
must diagnose what happened.
Often logging will be part of that.
Logging which is "too verbose" causes more than
just a performance hit; it can distract humans
from focusing on what matters.

> There is no way for a user of my library to change logging level without changing library's source code, which might not be possible when linking against binaries directly.

I am frankly skeptical of that claim,
and suspect that you simply have not yet tried to adjust logging
with zero source code changes.

Certainly if a Release build is not linked against logging output
routines, then we won't be seeing any log messages from such a binary.
For a Debug build you explain the default level is TRACE for all modules.

My reading of
https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/include/spdlog/cfg/env.h
suggests that a user with a Debug build could switch
to e.g. INFO severity for one or for all modules
by setting an environment variable.

```
    env_val = details::os::getenv("SPDLOG_LEVEL");
    if (!env_val.empty()) {
        helpers::load_levels(env_val);
    }
```

Based on the OP concerns expressed,
it sounds like you might want to

- test this, and
- document this behavior in your README.

Comment: If you do do this, you might want to ensure your loggers are all named appropriately, and those names documented, so that if the consuming application also uses the same library, they can configure their loggers through this mechanism without effecting yours.